# Firebase auth gives error when decoding ID token on backend for android but not for web

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase auth for authenticating users via facebook. I have a website and an android app. The ID token generated on the website is decoded and the auth data is retrieved without any problem. However, when decoding the ID token that is received from the android app, it gives an error:

```
    errorInfo:                                                                                               
    {
        code: 'auth/argument-error',
        message: 'Firebase ID token has invalid signature. See  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens
        for details on how to retrieve an ID token.' },
        codePrefix: 'auth'
    }
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated!

**UPDATE**: The error code 'auth/argument-error' is no where to be found in the official docs ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors)). Could this be an error caused due to different versions?

Comment: did  you find a solution?